# How to push a UI update to the mean thread in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I have a class called "Test" that has a property named "counter". When I create an instant of Test, I use CACurrentMediaTime() to update counter on an alternative queue using NSOperationQueue.
Here is my viewController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateTimerLabel) name:@"timerLabelUpdate" object:nil];

- (void) updateTimerLabel { 
        [self->_timerLabel setIntValue:[self->_test counter]];
    });
```

The problem is .. on my viewController I keep getting this error message:

> -[NSControl setIntValue:] must be used from main thread only

Does anyone know what I should do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the UI must be updated on the main thread.
You simply need to push the update method updateTimerLabel to the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self->_timerLabel setIntValue:[self->_test counter]];
    });
```

Let me know if this helps.